# Polygon array.filter() typeError

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, polygon

I have an array called `coordinate` which stores the latitude and the longitude of a polygon. I want to get the max and min latitude/longitude stored in this array.

My logic is to use `array.filter()` method to filter the values but my console keeps on saying

> coordinate.filter is not a function

```
// this is to get coordinate(lat and lng) of a map, lats and lng are being stored in array named coordinate

var coordinate = [];

for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    coordinate  += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + ",";
}

var results =coordinate.filter(function(value) {
    return(value< 0);
}
);

alert(coordinate);
})
```

Comment: add your code in the question.

Comment: I think you should use `coordinate.push(polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6))` instead of `coordinate  += polygon.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(6) + ",";`

Comment: How to get the min lat/lng and max lat/lng from the array coordinate? thank you for helping.

Comment: `coordinate` is a string, not an array.  A string doesn't have a `filter` method

Comment: i think that i defined coordinate as an array see the code above :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that your coordinate is an array. Looking into your comments you want to find min and max in your coordinate array which can be done by following:

```
if(Array.isArray(coordinate)){
 let min = coordinate.reduce((a,b) => Math.min(a,b));
 let max = coordinate.reduce((a,b) => Math.max(a,b)); 
}
```

Comment: i tried to alert the values, it is saying NaN :/... what if i use coordinate.filter() ? thank you for helping :)

Comment: Can you log the array and show in what format it is coming and edit it on the question. I mean the coordinate array. Filter can also be used depending upon what kind of array it is. Normally for computation reduce is better.

Comment: hey i tested it it worked but i wanted to get the max/min lat and max/min lng separately  any idea how i could do this ?

Comment: hahaha i trimed the String and then converted the string to float :'D Thank you dude!! you are the best <3